# Обратиться к свойству объекта, используя строковой путь

Tags: javascript

Есть ли в `JavaScript` возможность обратиться к объекту иерархической структуры, используя строку? То есть, структура, допустим, такая:

- Object 1

  - Object 2 > Field

И количество вложенных объектов неизвестно. Искомое поле может находиться как в корне (`Object 1`), так и на любом уровне вложенности. Можно сделать это рекурсивно, но вот задаюсь вопросом, нет ли такой возможности или какой-нибудь хитрости в `JavaScript`, позволяющей задать строкой путь к свойству и по этой строке считать или записать его значение?

Comment: eval("var value = " + objpath);

Comment: Посмотрите задачу об односвязанном списке на learn.javascript.ru в главе "перебирающие методы массивов".

Comment: Вопрос старый, но все же, лишним не будет https://github.com/mariocasciaro/object-path - реализация геттера/сеттера по строковому пути

Answer (score 2):

```js
var test = {
  level1: {
    level2: {
      value: "abc"
    }
  }
};

var path0 = "level1";
var path1 = "level1.level2.value";
var path2 = "level1.level2";
var path3 = "level1.bad.path";

function GetByPath(obj, path) {
  var parts = path.split(".");
  var current = obj;
  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    current = current[parts[i]];
    if (!current)
      break;
  }
  return current;
}

console.log(GetByPath(test, path0));
console.log(GetByPath(test, path1));
console.log(GetByPath(test, path2));
console.log(GetByPath(test, path3));
```

`SetByPath` - оставлено в качество упражнения.